# How to add class to (or change class of) a form field if it is empty? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form like below;

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
  <input type="text" class="required" value="" name="qwer" /><br />
  <input type="text" value="" name="asdf" /><br />
  <input type="text" class="required" value="" name="zxcv" /><br />
  <input type="text" value="" name="tyui" /><br />
  <input type="text" class="required" value="" name="ghjk" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to check if the text fields with `class="required"` is blank or not at the time of submission. If they are blank, I want to change the corresponding blank field's class to `error`. If all the required fields are not empty, I want to alert the serialized data. I've tried this;

```
$('#myform input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#myform').serialize();
  if($.trim($('#myform input[type=text].required').val()).length == 0){
    $(this).addClass("error");
  }else{
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

How can I do this? **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/6844R/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop over every element with the `required` class.
You are setting the error class on the submit button because you use `$(this).addClass()`, the `$(this)` is a reference to the submit button.

```
$('#myform input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#myform').serialize();

    [].slice.call($('#myform input[type=text].required')).forEach(function (elem, index) {
        $elem = $(elem);
        if($elem.val().length == 0)
            $elem.addClass("error");    
    }); 


});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6844R/1/)

---

Fyi: HTML5 comes with a bunch of pseudo-classes to check for invalid form inputs so you don't have to code it by yourself, take a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/) if you're interested.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, check out my answer too. It is simple

Answer (score -1):

After removing the unnecessary `value=""` on inputs

You can do this:

```
$('#myform input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#myform').serialize();
    if ($('.required').is('[value=""]')) {
        $('.required[value=""]').addClass("error");
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6844R/2/)

Comment: but how to implement `trim()` here?